# Qt send data from form1 into form2 treeview component

Tags: c++, excel, qt, treeview

I am pretty new to Qt, but I guess  that I need to use signals and slots to send/receive data, at least in tutorials and other posts it's always like that.

This should be working:

Push `Import` button, select xls file -> right after we've selected it. We are running through the file and get the same sheet name and sheet table column headers for each sheet (then the user selects the column and all what that column contains; we are inserting into a database, etc)

I want to make a GUI application like this in my "excel-2-some-db" module:

[image]

I got two classes. First one - import_module:

#### import_module.h:

```
#ifndef IMPORTDB_MODULE_H
#define IMPORTDB_MODULE_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QAxObject>
#include <QAxWidget>
#include "ui_importdb_module.h"
#include "headers_selection.h"//select form

class importdb_module : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    importdb_module(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~importdb_module();

    //...

private:
    Ui::importdb_moduleClass ui;

    //...

    headers_selection* select_form;

public slots:
    void on_getExcelPath_clicked();
    void on_pushButton1_clicked();

    //signal we will send after read some sheets columns
signals:
    void sendTreeViewData(QString &sheet_name, QStringList &sheet_headers);

};

#endif // IMPORTDB_MODULE_H
```

#### import_module.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
 #include <QApplication>
#include "importdb_module.h"


importdb_module::importdb_module(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    select_form = new headers_selection();

    //to show form on click
    connect(ui.pushButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()), select_form, SLOT(show()));

    connect(this, 
    SIGNAL(sendTreeViewData(QString &sheet_name, QStringList &sheet_headers)), 
    select_form, 
    SLOT(recieveTreeViewData(QString &sheet_name, QStringList &sheet_headers))); 

}

importdb_module::~importdb_module()
{

}

//....

//all file headers
void importdb_module::readSheetsHeaders(QAxObject* &_workbook, QAxObject* _worksheets, QAxObject* &_excel){
    QAxObject* sheet_i; 
    int sheets_count = _worksheets->property("Count").toInt(); //get how much lists there, gonna choose one to import data

    QString sheet_name;
    QStringList sheet_headers;//sheet headers will store here

    //sheets num starts from 1
    for(int i=1; i<= sheets_count; i++){
        sheet_i = _workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", i);//get teh list
        sheet_name = sheet_i->property("Name").toString();//get teh name

        //...
        getTableHeaders(sheet_i, sheet_headers);

        //says that we've send tree data into the form
        emit sendTreeViewData(sheet_name, sheet_headers);


        sheet_i->clear();
        sheet_headers.clear();
    }

    delete sheet_i;
};

//...
```

#### headers_selection.h

```
#ifndef HEADERS_SELECTION_H
#define HEADERS_SELECTION_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "ui_headers_selection.h"

class headers_selection : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    headers_selection(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~headers_selection();

private:
    Ui::headers_selection ui;


public slots:
    void recieveTreeViewData(QString &sheet_name, QStringList &sheet_headers);


};

#endif // HEADERS_SELECTION_H
```

#### headers_selection.cpp

```
#include "headers_selection.h"

headers_selection::headers_selection(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;




}

headers_selection::~headers_selection()
{

}

void headers_selection::recieveTreeViewData(QString &sheet_name, QStringList &sheet_headers)
{
        //just test
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;

model->setColumnCount(1);
model->setRowCount(5);
model->setData(model->index(0, 0), "some data0");
model->setData(model->index(1, 0), "some data1");
model->setData(model->index(2, 0), "some data2");
model->setData(model->index(3, 0), "some data3");
model->setData(model->index(4, 0), "some data4");

ui.treeView->setModel(model);
}
```

And after I import `.xls` and opening treeview selection windows - it's empty!

So I got two possible problems here

maybe `sendTreeViewData` does not invoke `recieveTreeViewData` or maybe I do something wrong with tree view inside `recieveTreeViewData` method.

Could somebody help me to fix it, please?

**UPDATE**

Well, I made a little changes (thanks to [thomas_b,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1702266/thomas-b) his answer shown me the way) in code and now it works!

```
//impordb_module.h
signals:
    void sendTreeViewData(QString &sheet_name, QStringList &sheet_headers);

//heaqders_selection.h
public slots:
    void recieveTreeViewData(QString &sheet_name, QStringList &sheet_headers);

//heaqders_selection.cpp
void headers_selection::recieveTreeViewData(QString &sheet_name,  QStringList &sheet_headers)
{
    qDebug()<<sheet_name<<" gotcha! ";
}

//in impordb_module.cpp
importdb_module::importdb_module(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags): QMainWindow(parent, flags){

connect(this, SIGNAL(sendTreeViewData(QString &,QStringList &)), select_form, SLOT(recieveTreeViewData(QString &,QStringList &)));
}
//...

void importdb_module::readSheetsHeaders(QAxObject* &_workbook, QAxObject* _worksheets, QAxObject* &_excel){


        //...
        getTableHeaders(sheet_i, sheet_headers);

        //says that we've send tree data into the form
        emit sendTreeViewData(sheet_name, sheet_headers);
  //...
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your connection failed because of the parameter names in your connect statement. Try change it to:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendTreeViewData(QString,QStringList)), 
    select_form, SLOT(recieveTreeViewData(QString,QStringList)));
```

Comment: Oh and in debug output log there apperaed such messages:
`>Object::connect: No such signal importdb_module::sendTreeViewData(QString,QStringList)`
`>Object::connect:  (sender name:   'importdb_moduleClass')`
`>Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'headers_selection')`

Comment: Well, I chaned signatures in signals/slots everywhere, even in void `headers_selection::recieveTreeViewData(QString, QStringList)` and now it activates. But how to get data which should be sent?